# Como capturar o evento onRendered de um canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Como saber se o canvas está pronto?

Estou utilizando a [biblioteca fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/), que cria uma estrutura de elementos complexos dentro de um canvas, porém eu gostaria de chamar uma função callback depois que o canvas tivesse todos os elementos complexos carregados.

O html2canvas faz algo similar, porém não funciona com o fabricjs:

```
html2canvas($('#my_canvas'), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
   //SIMILAR A ISSO
  }
});
```

O que eu consigo ter é o total de elementos do meu canvas:

```
 var totalItens = canvas.getObjects().length;
```

E estou processando um tempo baseado na quantidade, o problema é que pode haver 1 único item muito complexo, e a ação pode não ter um bom comportamento enquanto ainda estiver sendo carregada no navegador:

```
var calc = (totalItens * 400), 
    tempoDoProcesso = (calc) > 6000 ? 6000 : calc

setTimeout({
 //faço a ação...
}, tempoDoProcesso);
```

O canvas começa a travar quando tem muitos itens na tela... e por isso, fica impossível fazer qualquer evento antes do processo ter finalizado.

Comment: Você leu a documentação? http://fabricjs.com/events

Comment: `canvas.on("after:render", function() {})`. Fonte: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

Comment: Eu li sim, mas não encontrei a informação muito clara, tive dificuldades em achar a solução, um colega meu também procurou comigo aqui e não achou... se vc notar nesse link de events, ele é o último da lista, passou batido. Aliás muito dos eventos que tenho utilizado na lib, tive que caçar por aí...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá Ivan e para outros programadores.

Você lendo a documentação de eventos no site da fabric.js vai entender tudo.

Antes de usar uma nova biblioteca javascript leia a documentação pra usar corretamente e não haver problemas.

Solução:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('my-canvas');
canvas.on("after:render",function() {
  console.log("render on")
});
```

Fonte:
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

Comment: Valeu @AnittaDeveloper, era isso que eu estava procurando...